# Pro-mortal mythological gods = Tau'ri allies?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In SG1S1E10, Daniel describes 2 types of Star gods:

- the Tyrants
- the Culture bearers

The Tyrants were equaled with the Goa'uld. While on the other hand there was Thor as a friend and protector of humans.
But is this distinction sufficient?
What about Athena, Isis, Osiris, Horus/Heru'ur, Olokun, Thoth,...?
I would say that mythology portrays them in quite the favorable way, as such why do they not help the Tau'ri?
Or are they just the selected few rational Goa'uld?

Comment: [Athena = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Athena). [Isis = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Isis), [Osiris  = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Osiris), [Horus = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Heru%27ur), [Olokun = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Olokun), [Thoth = Baddie](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Thoth). Basically they're all baddies.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Daniel is describing the Goa'uld as the tyrants and the Asgard as the culture bearers. We've not come across many (any?) good Goa'uld that existed on Earth in ancient times.

Comment: @Valorum Technically speaking, the Tok'Ra are the good Goa'ulds, however they didn't have any impact on humanity in the SG1 mythos as far as I'm aware.

Comment: So, roughly speaking, Norse gods = good on Stargate. Non-Norse = bad, be they logical choices like Kali, Ares, or Balor, or completely weird choices like Amaterasu, Indra, and the Jade Emperor. It's really weird that the Norse gods were apparently "culture-bearers," whereas the deities of much larger and more developed societies in the rest of Europe, Africa, and Asia were apparently mere tyrants.

Comment: Don't forget the South American/Olmec/Aztec/Inca/Mayan temple aliens who are the enemy of our enemy. Although it appears at least one South American god was a Goa'uld - the creator of the sarcophagus tech.

Comment: Yu was several times described as "not as bad as others", if not "sometimes benevolent". Certainly some of his actions are not quite Goa'uld-like... And there were also Ohnes (Nem and Omoroca), as well as Serrakins...

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Greek gods were occasionally helpful towards certain humans, but when you take a step back and look at them on a whole, they really treated humans more like playthings than anything else. Take Athena for instance, Harmonia (illegitimate daughter of Aphrodite and Ares) was given a cursed necklace and robe by Athena and Hephaistos at her wedding because her mother cheated on her father.

I don't think the Culture Bearers were Goa'uld at all. Look at S1 E13 "Fire and Water". That was an alien looking for Omoroca, who Daniel would have categorized as a Culture Bearer based on what he told Nem (Omoroca's husband, and the alien questioning him) about her. Considering this episode and the eventual arrival of the Asgard into the story, the other Culture Bearers were probably other alien races that were opposed to the Goa'uld that eventually either lost the fight with them, or moved on like the Ancients.

Answer (score -6):

The fact that the Goa'uld (and other aliens) existed and interfered with Earth cultures means that the Stargate universe is similar to ours, but not exactly the same.

So, there's no guarantee that the mythology of Stargate would exactly match our own.